# Is it possible to use Grails validation outside of Grails? How?

Tags: validation, grails, groovy, constraints, grails-validation

Grails has amazing validation; is it possible to use it independent of the Grails framework?

We have a Java/Groovy Camel-based web application we can't convert to a Grails application.  I'd love to use the Grails-style validation with the declarative constraints but have been unable to successfully configure the application to work with Grails libraries without converting the whole thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The validation provided by Grails is just a wrapper around Spring's bean validation framework. Since Grails is open source you can take a look at how it's done and adapt it to your own needs. The best place to start looking is the [GrailsDomainClassValidator](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-core/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/validation/GrailsDomainClassValidator.java) and [DomainClassGrailsPlugin](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-plugin-domain-class/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/DomainClassGrailsPlugin.groovy) to get an idea of how it's done. Another point of interest would be the [@Validateable](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-plugin-validation/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/compiler/validation/ValidateableTransformation.java) AST annotation.

As far as I know, and from what I can see in the source, there isn't a stand alone way to do this outside of a Grails project without writing your own adaptation/implementation.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a external validation without problem. It is possible, for example, using a external "jar" (that do a validation) file on the "lib" folder of your Grails project. Through this way, you can use the API of this jar file. It's a simple way that you can use.